# Turning Array Into String in SnapLogic

Tags: arrays, snaplogic

I have the output of a SalesForce SOQL snap that is a JSON in this format.

```
[
  {
    "QualifiedApiName": "Accelerator_Pack__c"
  },
  {
    "QualifiedApiName": "Access_Certifications__c"
  },
  {
    "QualifiedApiName": "Access_Requests__c"
  },
  {
    "QualifiedApiName": "Account_Cleansed__c"
  },
  {
    "QualifiedApiName": "Account_Contract_Status__c"
  }
]
```

I am attempting to take those values and turn them into a string with the values separated by commas, like this, so that I can use that in the SELECT clause of another query.

```
Accelerator_Pack__c, Access_Certifications__c, Access_Requests__c, Account_Cleansed__c, Account_Contract_Status__c
```

From the documentation, my understanding was that .toString() would convert the array into a comma-separated string, but as shown in the attached image, it isn't doing anything.  Does anyone have experience with this?

[image]

Comment: You need to aggregate the documents. Otherwise, you won't be able to process all the elements in the array at once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate the incoming documents.

Use the `Aggregate` snap with the function `CONCAT`. This will give you a `|` delimited concatenated string as the output like as follows.

```
Accelerator_Pack__c|Access_Certifications__c|Access_Requests__c|Account_Cleansed__c|Account_Contract_Status__c
```

You can then replace the `|` with `,` like `$concatenated_fields.split('|').join(',')` or `$concatenated_fields.replace(/\|/g, ',')`.

Following is a detailed explanation of the configuration.

*Sample Pipeline:*

[image: Sample Pipeline]

*Sample Input:*

I set the sample JSON you provided in a `JSON Generator` for testing.

[image: Sample Input]

*Aggregation:*

[image: Aggregation]

*Result of Aggregation:*

You get a `|` delimited concatenated string.

[image: aggregate output]

*Mapper Expression:*

[image: mapper]

*Output:*

Both expressions give the same result.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the array functions directly to achieve this. see the below pipeline that can be used to concat the values:

[image]

I have used the JSONGenerator for taking your sample data as input.
Then I have used the GroupByN snap with '0' as the group size to formulate the array.

[image]

Finally in the mapper you can use the below expression to concat:

jsonPath($, "$arrayAccom[*].QualifiedApiName").join(",")

[image]